# Getting error when passing value into object

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code within my ASP.net project. I am trying to store some values into my object with my web form, but it pops up an error message saying: Cannot implicitly convert type 'short' to 'string'.

```
    textbox.Text = Convert.ToInt16(object.number);
    lstbox.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt16(object.ID);
```

Within my object class, I have declared my variables to int. Please let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Text` and `SelectedValue` properties are strings. Why would you convert the values to `short` in the first place?

```
textbox.Text = object.number.ToString();
lstbox.SelectedValue = object.ID.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign non-string values to a property which accepts string/text values. In your case, you are trying to assign a short value to text property of textbox. Please cast the value to string using `Convert.ToString` or `ToString()`.

So your code should be

```
textbox.Text = Convert.ToString(object.number);
```

or

```
textbox.Text = object.number.ToString();
```

Scenario is same while assigning the selected value property of listbox.

```
lstbox.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(object.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Both of your code works to cancel out the error and my project is running smoothly now. Still have a question, does my object now have string value variables or int?

Comment: No, the existing value of your object won't change, we are just casting the value for the purpose of assigning only.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to pass the value to the object, you should have the object's variables = the input value.

```
    object.number = Convert.ToInt16(textbox.Text);
    object.ID = Convert.ToInt16(lstbox.SelectedValue);
```